# Dax Many to Many Measure with Calender Date filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 Tables:

- 1CALENDAR DATE TABLE with Active Single Relationship to 2Date
  Enquired and to 3Date Contacted
- 2Fact1
- 3Fact2

2Fact1 :
Mobiles DateEnquired EnqType

3Fact2 : Mobiles DateContacted

2Fact1 and 3Fact2 don't have an active relationship
Many to Many using Mobiles

Help me find the Measure code Required to calculate count of 2Fact1Mobiles if Date Contacted is greaterthan or equals to Date Enquired

Examples
Filter is March Calendar Date Table
12345 Enquired is 24 March
12345 Contacted is 10 March
Correct Result is 0

Filter is 2024 Calendar Date Table
9999 Enquired 1 Jan
9999 Enquired 20 March x
9999 Contacted 1 Jan
9999 contacted 2 Feb
9999 Contacted 3 Mar
Correct Result is 1

I may have found the solution just by asking this question, seems like simplifieng the issue clears the buzz.

The issue I am having is the column totals dont match when breaking it down by Enquiry Type for example.
I get results like
Type 1 is 10 Mobiles
Type 2 is 4 Mobiles
Total is 12

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.